# Left outer join with multiple where condition with LINQ giving null reference error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to do a left outer join on two tables, I tried following:

```
var EducationDetails = (from e in DataContext.HRM_EMP_EDUCATION.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.EMP_CODE == Employee_Code)
                                from ex in DataContext.HRM_EDUCATION.Where(x => x.EDU_TYPE == "EXAM" && x.EDU_CODE == e.EXAM_CODE).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new HRM_EMP_EDUCATIONModel
                                {
                                    EXAM_NAME= ex.EDU_NAME==null? "N/A":ex.EDU_NAME
                                }).ToList();
```

when e.Exam code is null, I'm getting the error. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Getting *what* error? `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Yes, I did it before with one condition in the where clause, but now getting the error.

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` Don't do that...you are running the query locally.

Comment: PS. Please clarify WHICH you are using `linq-to-sql` or `linq-to-entities`. I highly doubt this code is being run on both.

Comment: Sorry for being brief in my question, I'm using linq-to-entities. I tagged both to draw more attention. Anyway after removing the .AsEnumerable(), it seems working! Let me check a little more, then I will confirm you. Thanks.

Comment: @Jain that will make the difference because when using L2E a query will never return `null`, it will return an empty collection. You should be aware of the consequences of using `AsEnumerable`; it effectively runs any code after that call in memory. It can be useful in some situations where L2E doesn't fully support the query you need to run. However, in your case it's unnecessary.

Comment: ok, since I need to some properties to string in selection, I tried to use ToString() method, but when not using the AsEnumerable(), its giving an error saying method not supported. How to use ToString() mehtod in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the condition `ex.EDU_NAME==null` to `ex==null?`

since left outer join ex can be null, when you check `EDU_NAME` property of null it will throw  `NullReferenceException`

if you need to check `ex` and `EDU_NAME` for null, you can change the condition as below

```
EXAM_NAME = (ex!= null || ex.EDU_NAME==null) ? "N/A":ex.EDU_NAME
```

Comment: Yes, It's working fine now. For further learning, can you please explain what to do if ex is not null but some properties say ex.Something is null? How to check for null in that case?

Comment: Check my update, first check the object and then you can check the properties.